# Reading from file upto a special character

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream, ifstream

I have a file whose contain is like this:

```
10003;Tony;Stark;6:3:1990;Avengers Tower;New York City;12222;Iron Man
```

I want to read it like this

10003

Tony

Stark

6:3:1990......

I have tried upto this but couldn't seems to go further. I am trying to read up to the `;`

```
 std::ifstream file;
 file.open ("OUT.txt")
 while (in)
    std::cout << char(in.get());
```

Comment: What's the special character you are talking about?

Comment: Semicolon ; I want to read upto semicolon

Answer (score 1):

```
You can read each line and you can assign letters to a string until detecting ';':    

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream file;
    file.open("/directory of ur txt file/example.txt",ios_base::app);
    string lines;        
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        getline(file,lines);
        string desired_word = "";

        for(int i=0;i<lines.length();i++)
        {
            if(lines[i] != ';')
              desired_word += lines[i];
            if(lines[i]==';')
            {
               cout<<desired_word<<endl;
               desired_word = "";
            }
        }

    }



    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::getline with ';' as the delimiter.

```
std::ifstream file;
file.open ("OUT.txt")
for (std::string item; std::getline(file, item, ';'); )
   std::cout << item << std::endl;
```